# Can I reload a single systemd unit/service file after its modification without reloading all unit files?

Tags: systemd

Can I reload a single systemd unit/service file after its modification (in [Service] section) without reloading all unit files? By online search, everyone talk about `systemctl daemon-reload` or `systemctl --user daemon-reload`. This makes me feel really bad. I only want to reload one unit file configuration instead of many. Is that possible to reload the modified one only in systemd? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you confusing `reload` with `daemon-reload`? Or in other words, why just only `daemon-reload` a single unit/service?

Comment: @Thomas I am not confusing reload and daemon-reload. I just want to daemon-reload a single unit service file because I modified the unit service file (the [Service] section). I heard `daemon-reload` will rerun all generators and reload all unit files from [this link](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemctl.html#daemon-reload). Thanks.

Comment: `daemon-reload` it not harmful and won't do a `systemctl reload ...`. As far as I know you cannot daemon-reload a single unit.

Comment: @Thomas ok thanks. I just friendly clarify once again I am NOT looking for `systemctl reload` at all. I am looking for `daemon-reload` a single unit file only. And thanks for the comment. That means it's not doable then. If you are sure it's not doable, you can provide it as the answer. I can then accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`systemctl daemon-reload` cannot be run on a single unit file. What it does is reloading the `systemd` configurations of unit files, rerun all generators and recreates the dependency tree.

I guess since the dependency tree is regenerated it doesn't make sense to run this on a single unit as several unit files may have changed and the dependency tree then could be wrong.